# Track bar /slider template for WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Im looking for a customized control for WPF which allows Min,Max values and Indicator on specific value.
If I had to paint it, It would look similar to this

[image]

In this example I have min =0, max= ~600, indicator=~200
500 indicates the point where my bar changes color

Comment: To me, this looks most similar to the [Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.110).aspx) control. That would be your best base, then just template/style it accordingly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to edit slider template to achieve your design slider. You can use Colors or Image for controls as per your choice. [Example- Modified slider template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136114/custom-wpf-slider-with-image-as-thumb/25137302#25137302)

For your question below template will work fine .

[image]

```
<Window.Resources>      
    
    <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border Background="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />           
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="YellowGreen"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="YellowGreen" Height="3"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />    
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Path Data="M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 Z"  Stroke="YellowGreen" Margin="-2,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="YellowGreen"></Path>
                        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="7" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1.5,1.5"></Line>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="-2,30,0,0"  Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TickBar  x:Name="TopTick"  Fill="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Top"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="0" Placement="Top" Height="5" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" ></Border>
            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Red" Height="3"   Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="0,-10,0,0"  >
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" Margin="0,-20,0,0" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <TextBlock Text="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Fill="LightGray"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="2"   Placement="Bottom" Height="4" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement"  Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter TargetName="BottomTick"  Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Slider Style="{StaticResource Horizontal_Slider}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TickFrequency="37.5" Minimum="0" Maximum="600" Value="500" Width="300" Margin="50,0,50,0"></Slider>
```

Comment: Can we use image inplace of color "Red" in background of slider ? as per your code i tried, and what i did, in sliderRepeatButton in ContentTemplate i used Ellipse and fill with imageBrush, but i am getting exception on UI. Please guide.

Comment: Yes we can use image insted of red color .instead of backgorund use imagebrush like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136114/custom-wpf-slider-with-image-as-thumb

Comment: hello how can I make it vertical?

Answer (score 1):

*Im looking for a customized control for WPF which allows Min,Max values and Indicator on specific value*

You mean, you're looking for the `Slider` Class. Why re-invent the wheel? Just declare your own `ControlTemplate` for it:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="500">
    <Slider.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
            <!-- define your ControlTemplate content in here -->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Slider.Template>
</Slider>
```

When declaring new `ControlTemplate`s, it always a good idea to start with the default one and slowly makes changes from there. you can find the default `Slider ControlTemplate` in the [Slider Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

You can find out more about the `Slider` class from the [`Slider` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.slider.aspx) page and more about `ControlTemplate`s from the [`ControlTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Your slider class link points to the progress bar class, maybe you can update the link?